# jquery ui dialogs initial position

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog

I am using JQuery dialog for creating dialog windows in my web app. $('.navbar') is the header navigation menu. My problem is when opening second dialog it opens straightly on the position of first dialog and though covers it. I want to set some offset to the coordinates of next dialog relative to the last one to get effect of cascading dialogs.
Some of my dialogs are really big that's why I place them just below my navbar:

```
var dialogOptions = {
            position: { my: "top", at: "bottom" , of: $('.navbar')}
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
  position: { 
    my: 'top',
    at: 'bottom',
    of: $('#YourPreviousDialog')
  }
});
```